# Two images covering whole webpage

Tags: html, css

I need to make a webpage that is fully covered by two pictures. Each picture has different size and each one should cover 100% of vertical space and 50% of horziontal space of the page(page divided into two halves in the middle of vertical space). How can i do this using html and css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code :

```css
html, body, .image {
  height: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.image-left {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/999/999);
}

.image-right {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/1000/1000);
}
```

```html
<div class="image image-left"></div>
<div class="image image-right"></div>
```